# Rows not showing properly

Tags: python-3.8

I am making a Table object where you can see the columns and rows. When I try updating the table, the table is not updated properly. Why is this?

This is my current code:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, headers, rows):
        self.headers, self.rows = list(headers), list(rows)
        self.content = [self.headers,
                        [i for i in self.rows]]

    def show(self):
        print(str(list(self.headers)).replace(", ", " | ").replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
        for i in self.rows:
            tp = str(i).replace(", ", " | ").replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            print(tp)

    def add(self, headers=None, rows=None):
        if headers:
            self.headers.extend(headers)
        if rows:
            self.rows.extend(rows)

    def update(self):
        self.content = [self.headers,
                        [i for i in self.rows]]


t = Table(["a", "b"], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
t.show()
print("-"*20)
t.add("c", [7, 8, 9])
t.update()
t.show()
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the output should be.  Could you please post the expected output for the second `t.show()`?

Comment: The second one?

Comment: Second one:

a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9

Oops, StackOverflow removed the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments I'm not quite sure about the expected output.  But if it is:

```
a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

Then you have to put additional brackets in your call to `add` method.  It is expecting a list of list as its second argument as far as I can tell. So:

```py
t.add("c", [[7, 8, 9]])
```

That does the job.